# Build dynamic web projects with maven in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, maven-2

I need the step by step details of running a web project using maven2 in eclipse.

> 1. where to put the web.xml and any other resource
> 2. what to put in web.xml
> 3. how to generate war file from maven

Please somebody hep me with the above points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new web project using maven, see http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-webapp.html

After you create it, use "mvn eclipse:eclipse" to create an eclipse project.

Comment: Or, if you use m2eclipse (which you should), select `import -> existing maven projects`

Comment: ye.. but where do i put my web.xml file?

Comment: @Anand If you follow the guide, you'll see a basic web.xml generated for you. Modify it upon your needs.